# Route 53 - Changing A type to AAAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, amazon-route53

I have terraform script that works well for `type=A` record DNS. So when I execute this:

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "this" {
  domain = "*.${var.CERTIFICATE_DOMAIN}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  name        = "${var.SERVICE}-${var.ENV}-${var.REGION}-allow_all"
  description = "Allow all inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.this.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "this" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.this.id}"

  tags {
    Service = "external"
  }
}

data "aws_security_groups" "ecs" {
  tags {
    Environment = "${var.VPC_ENV}"
    Region      = "${var.REGION}"
  }

  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = ["${data.aws_vpc.this.id}"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "group-name"
    values = ["${var.ENV}-api-internal-ecs-host*-sg"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "lb2ecs" {
  from_port                = 32768
  to_port                  = 65535
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${data.aws_security_groups.ecs.ids[0]}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.this.id}"
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_alb" "https" {
  name               = "${var.SERVICE}-${var.ENV}-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.this.id}"]
  subnets            = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.this.ids}"]
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  name         = "${var.CERTIFICATE_DOMAIN}."
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.this.zone_id}"
  name    = "${var.SERVICE}-${var.ENV}-${var.REGION}.${var.CERTIFICATE_DOMAIN}"
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = "${aws_alb.https.dns_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_alb.https.zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "https" {
  name     = "${var.SERVICE}-${var.ENV}-https"
  port     = 3000
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = "${data.aws_vpc.this.id}"

  health_check {
    path = "/health"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "https" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.https.arn}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2015-05"
  certificate_arn   = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.this.arn}"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.https.arn}"
  }
}
```

It properly creates new HTTPS endpoint and I can easily put service behind it (by linking the `aws_alb_target_group.https` with ECS service)

I need to add IPv6 support, so I was thinking - what about just changing the A type to AAAA in `resource "aws_route53_record" "www"`. The terraform was executed fine stating that it was changed, in Route 53 I can see the record looks exactly the same as before but it has AAAA type, but the service is not reachable anymore.

In Route 53, I can see that there is ALIAS that looks like this: someservice-test-alb-1395527311.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com. And I can reach the service with it by HTTPS from public internet. However the "nice" endpoint that was working before dont work anymore. Also `ping`ing the URL do not receive any IP anymore.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to read the docs about setting up IPV6: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-ip-address-type.html -- it's not just something you do by changing a DNS entry.

Comment: Additionally, you likely don't want to *change* from A to AAAA but rather you want to have both unless you really don't want IPv4 to work (which you didn't mention).

Answer (score 0):

AAAA records, you need to first enable your VPC with IPV6 support. By default its not enabled.
Once you are done than you can follow the guideline in below blog to enabled IPV6 for teraform.

https://medium.com/@mattias.holmlund/setting-up-ipv6-on-amazon-with-terraform-e14b3bfef577

Comment: The link in the comments on the question is a better documentation link than what you've added. Also, your answer as it stands is dangerously close to being just a link only answer. A bit more detail and including the link to the official AWS docs (as well as the Medium blog post if you think it adds enough) would improve this answer.